# react images upload how to update state array during onchange

Tags: reactjs

I am new at react and I am creating an upload images functionality using this: https://github.com/JakeHartnell/react-images-upload as a guide.

however i am having issues with the set state, it adds the file even if i removed it from the upload

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, i have added two photos, removed one and added one again. when i checked the state. it has 6 files in the array. how do i fix this one?

this is my onchange function:

```
 onDrop = picture => {
      this.setState({
        artistGallery: this.state.artistGallery.concat(picture),
      });
  };
```

i am calling it here:

```
 <ImageUploader
     withIcon={true}
     buttonText='Choose images'
     onChange={this.onDrop}
     imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
     maxFileSize={5242880}
     withPreview={true}
 />
```

Comment: how are you removing from `this.state.artistGallery` ?

Comment: @McRist thats actually what i wanted to know :(

Comment: can you tell what does it log on `console.log(picture)` in `onDrop function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `'onDrop'` function is getting called on `'add'` as well as on `'remove'` action. And you are concatinating the image files entries in `onDrop` thats why images entries are duplicated on each call.

In your case assuming '**picture**' is the array of images, Change your onDrop function to this:

```
onDrop = picture => {
      this.setState({
        artistGallery: picture
      });
};
```

Please note: I have tried this using the link you have provided in your question with react-images-upload.
Hope it helps!

P.S. I have raised a pull request on the [source](https://github.com/JakeHartnell/react-images-upload) you have used.