# React JS - onChange triggering twice

Tags: reactjs, upload, onchange

When I upload an image using react-image-uploader the onchange triggers twice. so it attempts to upload the image to the backend twice, here is how I handle it:

```
//user uploads image to app
<ImageUploader
   buttonClassName={"btn add-btn bg-orange"}
   buttonText='ADD'
   onChange={this.newProfilePicture}
   imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
   maxFileSize={5242880}
   fileSizeError="file size is too big"
   fileTypeError="this file type is not supported"
   singleImage={true}
   withPreview={true}
   label={""}
   withIcon={false}
/>



 //image is set to this.userprofilepicture
    newProfilePicture = (picture) => {
    this.setState({ userprofilepicture: picture});
    this.setNewProfilePicture();
    ShowAll();
}

//new profilepicture is uploaded to api
setNewProfilePicture = () => {
    let data = new FormData();
    console.log('profile picture: ', this.state.userprofilepicture)
    data.append('Key', 'profilePicture');
    data.append('Value', this.state.userprofilepicture)
    this.sendUpdatedPicture('uploadprofilepicture', data);
}
```

Is there a way to get this to only trigger once?

Comment: Did you bind `newProfilePicture` in the constructor?
like this
`this.newProfilePicture = this.newProfilePicture.bind(this)`

Comment: @Jin `newProfilePicture ` is an arrow function. There is no need to bind

Comment: @Jin No need to bind arrow functions

Comment: Kindly add link link of the component you are using. A [mcve] will be better. Are you using [react-images-upload](https://github.com/JakeHartnell/react-images-upload/issues/66)?

Comment: Hi @AbdulRauf, yes I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload react-images-upload

Comment: Have you checked similar issue linked in my previous comment related to ` react-images-upload`?. Solution of that issue is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981376/react-images-upload-how-to-update-state-array-during-onchange

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `create-react-app` then your `App`component is wrapped in `StrictMode` like this:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
```

go to **`index.js`** and remove `<React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>`

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageUploader
   buttonClassName={"btn add-btn bg-orange"}
   buttonText='ADD'
   onChange={event => this.newProfilePicture(event)}
   imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
   maxFileSize={5242880}
   fileSizeError="file size is too big"
   fileTypeError="this file type is not supported"
   singleImage={true}
   withPreview={true}
   label={""}
   withIcon={false}
/>
```

and in the function,

```
newProfilePicture = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...your code...
}
```

This should solve your issue, here we are stopping the event to be propagated to the next level. So that onChange executes only once.

Comment: When I try this fix, I get the error event.preventDefault() is not a function.

Comment: did you add this line `onChange={event => this.newProfilePicture(event)}`in <ImageUploader/>

Comment: Yeah, I've got it exactly how it was in your answer