# TextField calling handleChange twice

Tags: reactjs

My state start 0 initial, I want to use TextField in my form. It's type number and increment or decrement. When I click it gets 2 (state).

```
<TextField
 id="outlined-number"
 label="Quantity"
 value={value}
 onChange={(ev) => handleChange(ev)}
 type="number"
 className={classes.textField}
 InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
 }}
 margin="normal"
 variant="outlined"/>
```

I did a lot of search in stackoverflow, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819162/why-is-my-function-being-called-twice-in-react) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480107/react-js-onchange-triggering-twice) But my problem not solved.

I tried 
1:

```
onChange={handleChange}
```

2:

```
 ev.stopPropagation();
```

My handler function :

```
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    function handleChange(ev) {
        setValue(ev.target.value);
    }
```

It's start 0, When I clicked UP button and than changed 2. I don't understand where I made a mistake. Thanks for answer.

code : https://github.com/kvlknctk/cekilis/blob/volkancatak/src/app/main/market/AlertDialog.js

Comment: Remove parentheses : onChange={(ev) => handleChange}

Comment: I did, but not reaction. I put console.log("test") inside handleChange. But not execute.

Comment: Post your code complete.

Comment: https://github.com/kvlknctk/cekilis/blob/volkancatak/src/app/main/market/AlertDialog.js

Comment: In github code value variable  initial value is 1

Comment: It's not problem. My problem state increment twice. In this case state = 3

Comment: could it be related to this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17098

Comment: Ops, It's chromium bug. I tried on safari and work it. how abouth what will we do now? :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `create-react-app` then your `App`component is wrapped in `StrictMode` like this:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
```

go to **`index.js`** and remove `<React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode>`

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425